# count the frequency of a given word in text file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cpu-word, find-occurrences

I want to be able to count the number of occurrences of a given word (input for example) in a text file. I have this code and it gives me the occurrence of all the words in the file :

```
word_count = {}
    my_word = id
    File.open("texte.txt", "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
    words = line.split(' ').each do |word|
      word_count[word] += 1 if word_count.has_key? my_word
      word_count[word] = 1 if not word_count.has_key? my_word
    end
  end
end

puts "\n"+ word_count.to_s
```

thank you

Answer (score 6):

**Create a test file**

Let's first create a file to work with.

```
text =<<-BITTER_END
It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom,
it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of
incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was
the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, we had everything before us,
we had nothing before us...
BITTER_END

FName = 'texte.txt'
File.write(FName, text)
  #=> 344
```

**Specify the word to be counted**

```
target = 'the'
```

**Create a regular expression**

```
r = /\b#{target}\b/i
  #=> /\bthe\b/i
```

The word breaks `\b` are used to ensure that, for example, `'anthem'` is not counted as `'the'`.

**Gulp small files**

If, as here, the file is not humongous, you can gulp it:

```
File.read("texte.txt").scan(r).count
  #=> 10
```

**Read large files line-by-line**

If the file is so large that we'd want to read it line-by-line, do the following.

```
File.foreach(FName).reduce(0) { |cnt, line| cnt + line.scan(r).count }
  #=> 10
```

or

```
File.foreach(FName).sum { |line| line.scan(r).count }
  #=> 10
```

mindful that [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) made its debut in Ruby v2.4.

See [IO::read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-c-read) and [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach). (`IO.methodx...`is commonly written `File.methodx...`. This is permitted because `File` is a subclass of `IO`; i.e., `File < IO #=> true`.)

**Use gsub to avoid the creation of a temporary array**

The first method (gulping the file) creates a temporary array:

```
["the", "the", "the", "the", "the", "the", "the", "the", "the", "the"]
```

to which `count` (aka `size`) is applied. One way to avoid the creation of this array is to use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) rather than [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan), as the former, when used without a block, returns an enumerator:

```
File.read("texte.txt").gsub(r).count
  #=> 10
```

This could be used for each line of the file as well.

This is an unconventional, but sometimes helpful, use of `gsub`.

Comment: Interesting use of `gsub`. Too bad `text.count(r)` doesn't work, it would have been much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the count of a specific word, there is no need to use a `Hash`, for example:

```
word_count = 0
my_word = "input"

File.open("texte.txt", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    line.split(' ').each do |word|
      word_count += 1 if word == my_word
    end
  end
end

puts "\n" + word_count.to_s
```

`word_count` will contain the total number of occurrences of `my_word`.

---

If, on the other hand, you want to keep count of all words and then just print the count of a specific word, then you can use a `Hash`, but try something like this:

```
word_count = Hash.new(0)
my_word = "input"

File.open("texte.txt", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    line.split(' ').each do |word|
      word_count[word] += 1
    end
  end
end

puts "\n" + word_count[my_word].to_s
```

`word_count` will contain all words found with the total occurrences (words being the *keys* of the `Hash` and occurrences their *values*); to print the occurrences of `my_word`, you just need to get the value of the hash using `my_word` as key.

Comment: It keeps giving me 0

Comment: Or just `line.split(' ').count(my_word)`