# How to check with ruby if a word is repeated twice in a file

Tags: ruby

I have a large file, and I want to be able to check if a word is present twice.

```
puts "Enter a word: "
$word = gets.chomp

if File.read('worldcountry.txt') # do something if the word entered is present twice...
```

How can i check if the file `worldcountry.txt` include twice the `$word` i entered ?

Comment: Of course you're right, i have to use `File.read` but what to do after ? use `include?` `any?` how to detect the word twice ?

Comment: But that is not what you asked. The only question you ask is "do I have to use File.read?"

Comment: As for how to do it, that's kind of broad. Have you looked at Ruby's ways of searching a string? This is one of Ruby's strongest features. Show us your existing attempt and explain the difficulty for you.

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear.Yes i looked some ways to do that, i know how to find a string with `include?` or `any?` or `grep` but i don't know how to check if word is present twice.

Comment: @carlBloid _"do I have to use `File.read?`"_ – no you don't. For (very) large files or if your memory is limited, it might be better to use `IO.foreach` or `IO#each_line` which reads the file line by line. In addition, you could stop reading once you found the 2nd occurrence of your word (if you mean _at least_ twice) or the 3rd (if you mean _exactly_ twice) by `break`-ing out of the `foreach` / `each_line` loop.

Comment: At least twice or exactly twice? How large is the file?

Answer (score 1):

I found what i needed from this: [count-the-frequency-of-a-given-word-in-text-file-in-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43670273/count-the-frequency-of-a-given-word-in-text-file-in-ruby)

On the Gerry post with this code

```
word_count = 0
my_word = "input"

File.open("texte.txt", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    line.split(' ').each do |word|
      word_count += 1 if word == my_word
    end
  end
end

puts "\n" + word_count.to_s
```

Thanks, i will pay more attention next time.

Comment: Assuming you have an array of words in the file, you might just check `words.tally[my_word] == 2`.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not overly large, it can be gulped into a string. Suppose:

```
str = File.read('cat')
  #=> "There was a dog 'Henry' who\nwas pals with a dog 'Buck' and\na dog 'Sal'."
```

```
puts str
There was a dog 'Henry' who
was pals with a dog 'Buck' and
a dog 'Sal'.
```

Suppose the given word is `'dog'`.

**Confirm the file contains *at least* two instances of the given word**

One can attempt to match the regular expression

```
r1 = /\bdog\b.*\bdog\b/m
```

```
str.match?(r1)
  #=> true
```

[Demo](https://rubular.com/r/JOeFTseQ1Hmr2Y)

**Confirm the file contains *exactly* two instances of the given word**

Using a regular expression to determine is the file contains exactly two instances of the the given word is somewhat more complex. Let

```
r2 = /\A(?:(?:.(?!\bdog\b))*\bdog\b){2}(?!.*\bdog\b)/m
```

```
str.match?(r1)
  #=> false
```

[Demo](https://rubular.com/r/IzsczfKqwLDdtq)

---

The two regular expressions can be written in *free-spacing* mode to make them self-documenting.

```
r1 = /
     \bdog\b       # match 'dog' surrounded by word breaks  
     .*            # match zero or more characters
     \bdog\b       # match 'dog' surrounded by word breaks
     /m            # cause . to match newlines
```

```
r2 = /
     \A            # match beginning of string
     (?:           # begin non-capture group
       (?:         # begin non-capture group
         .         # match one character
         (?!       # begin negative lookahead
           \bdog\b # match 'dog' surrounded by word breaks
         )         # end negative lookahead
       )           # end non-capture group
       *           # execute preceding non-capture group zero or more times
       \bdog\b     # match 'dog' surrounded by word breaks
     )             # end non-capture group
     {2}           # execute preceding non-capture group twice
     (?!           # begin negative lookahead
       .*          # match zero or more characters
       \bdog\b     # match 'dog' surrounded by word breaks
     )             # end negative lookahead
     /xm           # # cause . to match newlines and invoke free-spacing mode
```